# Why google map API v2 show blank map?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

This is my code:

```
public class Map extends ActionBarActivity{

    GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        // Initializing
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
        markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        // Showing status
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            map = fm.getMap();

            if (map == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure my API key and permission are right. Because I used it for this project in the past and it's worked. But I don't know why it's not working now.
Can somebody show me why please? 
I changed my API key, but it still does not work.

Comment: what is the error you are seeing? status code?

Comment: I use real device. So I can not see status code. @Sunil B N.

Comment: But it's worked at the past. @Sunil B N

Comment: Can you post your logs?

Comment: As per the code you've to at least see the error message in case of failure. You don't see any error?

Comment: But I'm use real device. How to see the error message?

Comment: Try again from beginning, from creating new project to new API with package name. verify your permission, layout, in case you missed something.

Answer (score 0):

This is full code for googlemaps api v2 and work for me :

MapsActivity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    // Getting Google Play availability status
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    // Showing status
    if(status!= ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    }else { // Google Play Services are available

        // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // My location button
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // latitude and longitude
        double latitude = latitude;
        double longitude = longitude;

        // create marker
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("My Marker");

        // Changing marker icon
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_maps));

        // adding marker
        mMap.addMarker(marker);

        // changing camera map
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(11).build();

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 10, this);

    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Getting latitude of the current location
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();

    // Getting longitude of the current location
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Showing the current location in Google Map
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

/**
 * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
 * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
 * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
 * <p/>
 * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
 * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
 * <p/>
 * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
 * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
 * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
 * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
 * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
 */
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
 * just add a marker near Africa.
 * <p/>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
 */
```

and this the activity_maps.xml :

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

May can help

Comment: What is `// latitude and longitude
        double latitude = latitude;
        double longitude = longitude;` and `setUpMap();`? @Agung Harrys

Comment: @Hades10 you can delete it

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue...

1. Is the API Key configured correctly? Make sure you have the right sha1 or that you have none defined to make it public.
2. Make sure the Maps API is ENABLED. You must go into it and enable it.

Then test it with this simple code:

public final class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
  static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
  static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
  private GoogleMap map;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
        .title("Hamburg"));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(KIEL)
        .title("Kiel")
        .snippet("Kiel is cool")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

    // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
  }
```

manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
           android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
           android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait"
           android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" 
        android:value="API_KEY_HERE" />
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```